# What is the most accessible reference on wall-crossing?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds

I am looking for a nice and easy to read reference on wall-crossing (in the context of Donaldson theory). Is there some accessible reference you have to suggest? I am interested in studying Donaldson invariants for 4-manifolds with non-vanishing first Chern class being even. Wall crossing can appear there if I am not mistaken but I am still in the dark.